# How do I update a single value in a json document using jq?

Tags: json, jq

Appologies if I've overlooked something very obvious; I've just found `jq` and am trying to use it to update one JSON value without affecting the surrounding data.

I'd like to pipe a `curl` result into `jq`, update a value, and pipe the updated JSON to a `curl -X PUT`.  Something like

```
curl http://example.com/shipping.json | jq '.' field: value | curl -X PUT http://example.com/shipping.json
```

So far I've hacked it together using `sed`, but after looking at a few examples of the `|=` operator in `jq` I'm sure that I don't need these.

Here's a JSON sample--how would I use `jq` to set `"local": false`, while preserving the rest of the JSON?

```
{
  "shipping": {
    "local": true,
    "us": true,
    "us_rate": {
      "amount": "0.00",
      "currency": "USD",
      "symbol": "$"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 209, accepted):

You set values of an object using the `=` operator.  `|=` on the other hand is used to update a value.  It's a subtle but important difference.  The context of the filters changes.

Since you are setting a property to a constant value, use the `=` operator.

```
.shipping.local = false
```

Just note that when setting a value to a property, it doesn't necessarily have to exist.  You can add new values easily this way.

```
.shipping.local = false | .shipping.canada = false | .shipping.mexico = true
```

Comment: This sample is not good for normal value. So if you need change the normal value, you need add `"` with it, such as `.shipping.local = "new place"`. So the whole command will be `curl http://example.com/shipping.json | jq '.shipping.local = "new place"'`. Otherwise, you will get strange errors.

Comment: @BMW what? It's perfectly fine here. Any valid json value is valid, this just happens to be the literal `false`. Values do not have to be strings.

Comment: @BMW the OP wants to set it with `false`. What's wrong?

Comment: How would you set `.shipping.<INSERT VAR HERE>` where VAR is defined in jq?  For a simple example, how would you modify `jq --arg location local '.shipping.$location = false'` to make it work?

Comment: @MaxMurphy: `.shipping[$location] = false`

Comment: = sets, |= updates? In other words = can't add properties to an object?

Comment: @x-yuri: You absolutely can, the property you would set would be on the LHS. The only thing that changes between `=` and `|=` is what `.` is in the RHS.

Comment: Works for simple cases like in OP but breakdowns in anything more complex, e.g. set property `value` to `a` where property `key` on the object is `b`.

Comment: Imagine .shipping was nested 3 levels down and the parent keys were indeterminate so we could not match on them from the top.   But we want to update the `.shipping.us_rate.amount` where `.shipping.local=true` and `.shipping.us=true`.   How do we match and update the json, returning the whole document otherwise unchanged except for the updates?

Comment: @EdRandall Using this approach, you'd just have to search for that object you want to update and make the assignments. Just need to know how to identify what objects to update. But I'd imagine you could do: `(.. | objects | select(has("shipping")).shipping | select(.local == true and .us == true).us_rate.amount) = "blah"` (note the parentheses)

Answer (score 121):

Update a value (sets .foo.bar to "new value"):

```
jq '.foo.bar = "new value"' file.json
```

Update a value using a variable (sets .foo.bar to "hello"):

```
variable="hello"; jq --arg variable "$variable" '.foo.bar = $variable' file.json
```

Comment: This doesn't actually replace the contents of the file. It only prints to stdout. You will need to save stout back to the file to make the change persist. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60744617/1626687

Comment: This is great, thanks! Can you do an example for updating two properties at the same time, pretty please? 

Comment: For those wondering, you can literally pipe it:
`jq '.foo.bar = "new value" | .foo.baz = "other value"' file.json`

Answer (score 12):

a similar function to the operator |= is map.
map will be suitable to avoid the requirement of a previous filter for the array...

imagine that your data is an array (very common for this example)

```
[
  {
    "shipping": {
      "local": true,
      "us": true,
      "us_rate": {
        "amount": "1.00",
        "currency": "USD",
        "symbol": "$"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "shipping": {
      "local": true,
      "us": true,
      "us_rate": {
        "amount": "1.00",
        "currency": "USD",
        "symbol": "$"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

hence it is necessary to consider the array in the code as:

```
http://example.com/shipping.json | jq '.[] | .shipping.local = "new place"' | curl -X PUT http://example.com/shipping.json
```

or to use the map function that is crafted to work in every array element as

```
http://example.com/shipping.json | jq 'map(.shipping.local = "new place")' | curl -X PUT http://example.com/shipping.json
```

**Observation**

For the sake of those that are learning, you also did some mistakes in the jq usage, just consider that it does "read" the 1st parameter as the program, hence all the desired commands shall be included in the very first string after calling the program.

Comment: Why is this necessarily different to `.[].shipping.local = "new place"`?

Comment: the difference in this case, is the response, using the map function will give an array of objects, while to other option, you will a sequence of objects, one per line (useful to integrate to other interpreters as bash)

Comment: Based on your comments, isn't your answer missing the most important information: the difference in output?

Answer (score 1):

I defined a `test.json` with `{}` content and my `test.json` is empty when I try to change single field value by running following command:

```
jq '.test = "new-value"' test.json > test.json
```

After this command; `test.json` file content is empty. There is nothing.

The trick is that we need to echo to rewrite json file with modified data by running following command:

```
echo $(jq '.test = "new-value"' test.json) > test.json
```

This works for me.