# How can I update a secret on Kubernetes when it is generated from a file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-secrets

I've created a secret using

```shell
kubectl create secret generic production-tls \
  --from-file=./tls.key \
  --from-file=./tls.crt
```

If I'd like to update the values - how can I do this?

Answer (score 404, accepted):

This should work:

```shell
kubectl create secret generic production-tls \
--save-config \
--dry-run=client \
--from-file=./tls.key --from-file=./tls.crt \
-o yaml | \
kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: In the latest version of k8s, you'll need to provide `--save-config` to the `kubectl create secret` in order to avoid a CLI warning.

Comment: fyi, recent (Sept 2019) syntax that worked for tls secret: ```kubectl create secret tls my-domain-tls --namespace=default 
--key=./tls.key --cert=./tls.crt --dry-run -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -``` The certs were in plain text.

Comment: Need to use `--dry-run=client` with kubectl 1.18 or higher.

Comment: This will create "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration" with no encrypted values

Comment: @Froxz, the values in a Secret are not encrypted; they are simply base64 encoded. There is no change in security from using this command.

Answer (score 128):

You can delete and immediately recreate the secret:

```shell
kubectl delete secret production-tls \
--ignore-not-found

kubectl create secret generic production-tls \
--from-file=./tls.key \
--from-file=./tls.crt
```

I put these commands in a script. The `--ignore-not-found` prevents getting a warning on the first run.

Comment: what happens with pods while the secret is deleted?

Comment: @BrunoJCM running pods are not affected, no matter wether they get the secrets via env variables or mounted as volumes. If a pod i started in the time while there is no secret, they run into an error; therefore Janos' answer is the preferred way to go.

Comment: Yes, I see, using `apply` makes much more sense, thanks!

Comment: This was not working for me because I forgot the `--namespace=kube-system`

Comment: depends on what namespace you want to add the secret to, if not _default_ than of course you have to add the namespace argument.

Comment: I use this approach in CI scripts. But it produce race condition when several jobs run simultaneous and one script failed in case secret was deleted and not yet created. 
Be careful!

Comment: That solution is not equivalent to an update, as requested by the OP.

Deleting the secret means losing all metadata in the secret, as well as any other field in the secret.

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively, you can also use `jq`'s `=` or `|=` operator to update secrets on the fly.

```
TLS_KEY=$(base64 < "./tls.key" | tr -d '\n')
TLS_CRT=$(base64 < "./tls.crt" | tr -d '\n')
kubectl get secrets production-tls -o json \
        | jq '.data["tls.key"] |= "$TLS_KEY"' \
        | jq '.data["tls.crt"] |= "$TLS_CRT"' \
        | kubectl apply -f -
```

Although it might not be as elegant or simple as the `kubectl create secret generic --dry-run` approach, technically, this approach is truly updating values rather than deleting/recreating them. You'll also need `jq` and `base64` (or `openssl enc -base64`) commands available, `tr` is a commonly-available Linux utility for trimming trailing newlines.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31037640) for more details about `jq` update operator `|=`.

Comment: Can you just add `-w0` to disable line wrapping in the `base64` command? https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64

Comment: @chunk_split no. I am using macOS, the BSD version of the base64 command doesn't have that optioin.

Comment: Conceptually, assigning the values to variables increases the chances of them getting leaked into a log file when someone turns debugging on with `set -x`.

On a more practical level, since the jq arguments are between single quotes, the shell variables are not going to be expanded. Therefore, the final secret will have the literal characters $TLS_KEY and $TLS_CRT instead of their actual values.
You would need to do something like: 


jq --arg TLS_KEY $TLS_KEY '.data["tls.key"] |= "$TLS_KEY"'

Answer (score 14):

As I wasn't able to reply to Devy's answer above, which I like because it will preserve Ownership where deleting and recreating has the potential to lose any extra information in the record.  I'm adding this for the newer people who may not immediately understand whey their variables aren't being interpolated.

```sh
TLS_KEY=$(base64 < "./tls.key" | tr -d '\n')
TLS_CRT=$(base64 < "./tls.crt" | tr -d '\n')
kubectl get secrets production-tls -o json \
        | jq ".data[\"tls.key\"] |= \"$TLS_KEY\"" \
        | jq ".data[\"tls.crt\"] |= \"$TLS_CRT\"" \
        | kubectl apply -f -
```

This lead me to attempting to use the 'patch' method of kubectl, which also seems to work.

```sh
kubectl \
        patch \
        secret \
        production-tls \
        -p "{\"data\":{\"tls.key\":\"${TLS_KEY}\",\"tls.crt\":\"${TLS_CRT}\"}}"
```

Thanks Devy for the answer that best met my needs.

Comment: use `base64 -w 0` instead of `tr -d`

Comment: If you use `"stringData"` instead of `"data"` you don't need to base64 encode the value.

Answer (score 4):

*Late to the party but still here are my inputs.*

Potentially we can use both the `patch` or `edit` option.

- With `edit` :

  ```
  kubectl edit secrets/<SECRET_NAME> -n <NAME_SPACE>
  ```

  - ***NOT*** the recommended way of editing the secrets.
  - You should have enough permission to do the above edit.
  - The value should be `base64` encode by yourself and then the encoded value should be placed while editing.
- With `patch` :

  - this may help you [How to update secret with "kubectl patch --type='json'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55744582/how-to-update-secret-with-kubectl-patch-type-json)

Answer (score 3):

For more specific cases you might need to specify your namespace that the cert needs to be renewed and delete the old one.

**For deletion of the cert**

```
kubectl delete secret -n `namespace`
```

**For the creation of new cert to specific namespace**

```
kubectl create secret {your-cert-name} --key /etc/certs/{name}.com.key --cert /etc/certs/{name}.com.crt -n {namespace}
```

Comment: E.g.: One example `oc delete secret secret-name -n "openshift-config"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use patch secret:

```
kubectl patch secret my-secret  --patch="{\"data\": { \"tls.key\": \"$(base64 -w0 ./tls.key)\",\"tls.crt\": \"$(base64 -w0 ./tls.crt)\"  }}"
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you @Maoz Zadok. Slight adaptation needed for MacOS, the `base64` command requires an `-i` input parameter, and does not have a `-w` wrap parameter. Meaning: `kubectl patch secret tls-secret --patch="{\"data\": { \"tls.key\": \"$(base64 -i ./key.pem)\",\"tls.crt\": \"$(base64 -i ./cert.crt)\"  }}" `

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on these answers I found that adding '--ignore-not-found' to the delete helped with our CICD as it wouldn't error out if the secret didn't exist, it would just go ahead and create it:

```
kubectl delete secret production-tls --ignore-not-found
kubectl create secret generic production-tls --from-file=./tls.key --from-file=./tls.crt.
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found a best way to do so:

```sh
kubectl create secret generic production-tls --from-file=./tls.key  --from-file=./tls.crt --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```