# How to update secret with "kubectl patch --type='json'"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-secrets

I created a secret like this:

```
kubectl create secret generic test --from-literal=username=testuser --from-literal=password=12345
```

I want to update the username to `testuser2` but I want to do it only with `kubectl patch --type='json'`.

This is how I tried to do it:

```
kubectl patch secret test --type='json' -p='[{"data":{"username": "testuser 2"}}]' -v=1
```

But I received:

> The  "" is invalid

Remember, I want to do it with the option of `--type='json'`, no other workarounds.

Comment: the data object should not be inside square brackets, so instead of using '[{"data": ... }]' you can use '{ "data": ... } '

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found how to do it after I read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-a-json-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment) that referred me to [this](http://erosb.github.io/post/json-patch-vs-merge-patch/) great article.
This is the JSON secret:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "data": {
        "password": "aWx1dnRlc3Rz",
        "username": "dGVzdHVzZXI="
    },
    "kind": "Secret",
    "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": "2019-04-18T11:37:09Z",
        "name": "test",
        "namespace": "default",
        "resourceVersion": "3017",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/test",
        "uid": "4d0a763e-61ce-11e9-92b6-0242ac110015"
    },
    "type": "Opaque"
}
```

Therefore, to update the user's field I needed to create the JSON Patch format:

```
[
    {
        "op" : "replace" ,
        "path" : "/data/username" ,
        "value" : "dGVzdHVzZXIy" # testuser2 in base64
    }
]
```

Notice that the value should be in base64.

The result is:

```
kubectl patch secret test --type='json' -p='[{"op" : "replace" ,"path" : "/data/username" ,"value" : "dGVzdHVzZXIy"}]'
```

Comment: Thank you it works.
Note: if you PATCH secret with direct http request, Content-Type: application/json-patch+json have to be set.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do in order to replace the secret:

```bash
kubectl patch secret my-secret  --patch="{\"data\": { \"password\": \"$(echo -n mypassword |base64 -w0)\" }}"
```

You can either use `stringData` as a clear text,  as follow

```bash
kubectl patch secret my-secret  --patch='{"stringData": { "password": "mypassword" }}'
```

Comment: note that the patch should be an object `{}` and not a list of object `[{}]`

Answer (score 0):

This command solved my issue on version 1.24.x:

```bash
kubectl patch secret app-sec  --patch="{\"data\": { \"license-id\": \"TEST\" }}" -oyaml
```