# How to set secodary key for kubernetes ingress basic-auth

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I wanna have an ingress for all my service in the k8s, and give the ingress a basic auth. But for auth rotation, I want to support a secondary auth for user so the endpoint can be reached when they re-generate the primary key.

I currently can follow [this guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/basic/) to set up an ingress with single basic auth.

Comment: If you run the `htpasswd` command without the `-c` flag, so e.g. `htpasswd <filename> <username>` it will **add** an entry to the file rather than creating a new file from scratch. You could try then updating the `Secret` with the contents from that same file via [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45881259/1061413). Sounds like the `auth-secret` annotation is expected to be a "secret that contains username**s** and password**s**" (emphasis on the plural); see [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#authentication).

Comment: Could you try that and let me know if it works?

Comment: Actually, I just tried it out, will convert comments to an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adapting [the guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/basic/), you can put multiple usernames and passwords in the `auth` file you're using to generate the basic auth secret.  Specifically, if you run the `htpasswd` command without the `-c` flag, so e.g. `htpasswd <filename> <username>` it will **add** an entry to the file rather than creating a new file from scratch:

```
$ htpasswd -c auth foo
New password: <bar>
Re-type new password: <bar>
Adding password for user foo

$ cat auth
foo:$apr1$isCec65Z$JNaQ0GJCpPeG8mR1gYsgM1

$ htpasswd auth user2
New password: <pass2>
Re-type new password: <pass2>
Adding password for user user2

$ cat auth
foo:$apr1$isCec65Z$JNaQ0GJCpPeG8mR1gYsgM1
user2:$apr1$.FsOzlqA$eFxym7flDnoDtymRLraA2/
```

If you've already created the secret in the first place via the given command:

```
$ kubectl create secret generic basic-auth --from-file=auth
```

You can then update the secret with [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45881259/1061413):

```
$ kubectl create secret generic basic-auth --from-file=auth\
  --dry-run -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
Warning: kubectl apply should be used on resource created by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply
secret/basic-auth configured
```

You can confirm setting the secret worked:

```
$ kubectl get secret basic-auth -ojsonpath={.data.auth} | base64 -D
foo:$apr1$isCec65Z$JNaQ0GJCpPeG8mR1gYsgM1
user2:$apr1$.FsOzlqA$eFxym7flDnoDtymRLraA2/
```

Finally, you can test basic auth with both usernames and passwords is working:

```
$ curl http://<minikube_ip>/ -H 'Host: foo.bar.com' \
  -s -w"%{http_code}" -o /dev/null
401

$ curl http://<minikube_ip>/ -H 'Host: foo.bar.com' \
  -u 'wronguser:wrongpass' \
  -s -w"%{http_code}" -o /dev/null
401

$ curl http://<minikube_ip>/ -H 'Host: foo.bar.com' \
  -u 'foo:bar' \
  -s -w"%{http_code}" -o /dev/null
200

$ curl http://<minikube_ip>/ -H 'Host: foo.bar.com' \
  -u 'user2:pass2' \
  -s -w"%{http_code}" -o /dev/null
200
```