# How to insert fields into a JSON file using jq?

Tags: json, object, insert, key-value, jq

Let's say I have a JSON file `recipe.json` containing this:

```
{
            "name": "Curried Lentils and Rice",
            "ingredients": [
                {
                    "quantity": "1 quart",
                    "name": "beef broth",
                    "type": "Misc"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "1 cup",
                    "name": "dried green lentils",
                    "type": "Misc"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "1/2 cup",
                    "name": "basmati rice",
                    "type": "Misc"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "1 tsp",
                    "name": "curry powder",
                    "type": "Condiments"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "1 tsp",
                    "name": "salt",
                    "type": "Condiments"
                }
            ],
            "steps": [
                "Bring broth to a low boil.",
                "Add curry powder and salt.",
                "Cook lentils for 20 minutes.",
                "Add rice and simmer for 20 minutes.",
                "Enjoy!"
            ],
            "timers": [
                0,
                0,
                20,
                20,
                0
            ],
            "imageURL": "http://dagzhsfg97k4.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/lentils3.jpg"
}
```

And I'm trying to **insert** new JSON fields into the file at specific positions in the file, using **jq** such as:

```
"cuisine": "meditaranean"
```

will become the 2nd entry, and

```
"meal": "lunch"
```

will become the 4th entry. So the file after the command is like this:

```
{
            "name": "Curried Lentils and Rice",
            "cuisine": "meditaranean"
            "ingredients": [
                {
                    "quantity": "1 quart",
                    "name": "beef broth",
                    "type": "Misc"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "1 cup",
                    "name": "dried green lentils",
                    "type": "Misc"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "1/2 cup",
                    "name": "basmati rice",
                    "type": "Misc"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "1 tsp",
                    "name": "curry powder",
                    "type": "Condiments"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "1 tsp",
                    "name": "salt",
                    "type": "Condiments"
                }
            ],
            "meal": "lunch"
            "steps": [
                "Bring broth to a low boil.",
                "Add curry powder and salt.",
                "Cook lentils for 20 minutes.",
                "Add rice and simmer for 20 minutes.",
                "Enjoy!"
            ],
            "timers": [
                0,
                0,
                20,
                20,
                0
            ],
            "imageURL": "http://dagzhsfg97k4.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/lentils3.jpg"
}
```

My question is how to do this with **jq**?

Note: This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034746/how-do-i-update-a-single-value-in-a-json-document-using-jq) addresses performing updates of single fields, while the current question is about inserts. They are as different as orange and yellow bell peppers, which is different! (Don't make me add a picture of bell peppers to this post, I swear I'll do it if I have to.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update a single value in a json document using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034746/how-do-i-update-a-single-value-in-a-json-document-using-jq)

Comment: @JeffMercado - Methinks that is a different Q.  This one asks for the *addition* of a key/value pair at a specific spot.

Comment: Inserting and updating via jq is the same. If the element doesnt exist, it will create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a helper function, the task becomes trivial:

```
def insert_kv($key; $value; $ix):
  to_entries
  | .[0:$ix] + [{key: $key, value: $value}] + .[$ix:]
  | from_entries;

insert_kv("cuisine"; "mediterranean"; 1)
| insert_kv("meal"; "lunch"; 3)
```

You could (alternatively or in addition) define:

```
def insert_kv($object; $ix):
  to_entries
  | .[0:$ix] + ($object|to_entries) + .[$ix:]
  | from_entries;
```

Comment: what are `to_entries` and `from_entries` supposed to be here? is that a whole jq expression?

Comment: They are "well-known" builtin filters, and are documented in the jq manual: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/ . (One could alternatively use `with_entries/1` here.)

Comment: jq has an crud operations built in, why would you not use them?

Comment: @jonypony3 - which crud operation for inserting at a specific position do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Where your json is saved to meals.json, executing the following command will result into exactly what you need.

```
jq '.cusine="mediteranean"' meals.json
```